# JavaScript code formatter function for my website

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am in search for a single function to beautify code. I will get source code in a DIV dynamically. How can I format that code.. I don't want any command line tool.  Please someone help me..

I want a function like

```
  hilite($('.codeParent'));
```

This should replace code with formatted code.. I have googled and found many plugins but I could not find anything that suits to my need.

Comment: How about [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify)? Try it out 'live' here: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Google prettifier

http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

```
<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
<pre class="prettyprint">...</pre>
```

UPDATED:
I think you should take a look at https://github.com/einars/js-beautify from http://jsbeautifier.org/(I've never used before but I think it's ok).

Comment: That library is to highlight the code, Could you please suggest me a code formatter function.

Comment: @PrathapReddySV I've update my answer, you should try it, I guess :)